# Unity C# Локальные координаты объекта относительно родителя его родителя

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

У меня есть объект "Camera_Position" и "GunCamera" (Иерархия приведена ниже). Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы "GunCamera" перемещалась на место "Camera_Position" вне зависимости от положения родителей "Attachments", "Sight", "Scope_EOTech_XPS3" (Родители будут постоянно менять своё местоположение) но я не очень понимаю как такое можно сделать.

Или-же подскажите как получить локальные координаты "Camera_Position" относительно Префаба "Model_0"

[image: Вот сама иерархия]

Comment: Ну так перемещайте `.position` `GunCamera` к `.position` `Camera_Position`. Проблема та в чем... А координату одного объекта в координатной плоскости другова можно узнать как не странно через одни из методов трансформа [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html).

Comment: @Yaroslav Благодарю, метод Transform.InverseTransformPoint мне очень помог! Очень сильно ты мне помог